# Why photodiode measures random phase superpositions on continuous-wave (10kHz) white light?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, experimental-technique, experimental-technology, sensor

I measured a 10 kHz modulated white light using a photodiode ([Thorlabs PDA10A](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=PDA10A&pn=PDA10A#11887)):

[image]

Unexpectedly, the photodiode output sensitively depends on the orientation and position of the photodiode. For two positions with subtle difference, I got two measurements, as:

[image]
[image]
*Left: Random phase superposition (unexpected); Right: Stable measurement (expected).*

Other observations:

- This issue is not due to the driver or the signal generator. Everytime I moved the photodiode away from the stable position to a new position, likely there will be random phase superpositions as above left.
- Also, I have tried changing light source to a 632.8 nm laser diodes, yet same thing happens.
- If leaving the stable status running for long time (>10 min), the random phase superposition happens again. However I am not sure if this is because of the driver or the photodiode.
- The photodiode I used, there is a piece of cover glass in front of the sensing area. I am not sure if multi-reflection could cause this effect.

Questions:

- Why this random phase issue happens?
- How can I suppress it?

---

**Edits**

- I have used a lens to focus the light onto the photodiode.
- I cannot reproduce the stable status anymore, even with my previous setup. So something must be wrong with the driver.
- With an FFT on 4kHz data, we see: (note the waveform itself is not as good as it looks)

[image]
[image]
*Left: without driver, LED directly connects to signal generator, still phase-random; Right: with driver, and we see 4 kHz, 8 kHz, 12 kHz ... frequencies.*

- For the driver part, I was using analog modulation. Is analog modulation possible to produce such a random phase phenomenon?

Comment: The first thing I would check is to see if there is any stray EM signal that could be affecting your readings.  You could, for example, focus the light to a point farther away, use shielded wires, etc.

Comment: Does your scope have an FFT option? Would be interesting to see the frequency spectrum in the two positions.

Comment: @S.McGrew I have changed the setup to your suggestion, but it seems the issue still exists.

Comment: @boyfarrell, please see my edits for the FFTs. it seems there are many sub-frequencies in the waveform.

Comment: Ok. What happens if you reduce the frequency to say 100Hz? What happens if you connect the scope directly to driver? Do you see a clean signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the cable (connecting between signal generator and the laser driver) from

[image]
 to
[image]

Now the output is expected, and does not depend on orientation orposition of the photodiode.

Comment: Glad to see that a coax cable (a shielded wire) solved your problem.